# Rails SQL query where column like?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I'm writing an autocomplete query in Rails which returns items that BEGIN with what is typed. How do I extend this to include all words in a sentence?

Example:

Item: add records from console

If the user searches for 'console' how do I include this in the results and still keep the first condition?

**My query**

```
SubCategory.where("name LIKE ?", "#{params[:q]}%")
```

[image: order resullts]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, if the input is *bla*, then you want

- names that begin with *bla*
- and names that have a space followed by *bla*

That would be:

```
YourModel.where("name LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?", "#{term}%", "% #{term}%")
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that works perfect but what if I want to include both in the results. Say I have 5 records that begin with bla, I want to show them first but under them I want to also include ones that don't start with bla but have a space and then include bla. Will this work multiple levels deep? Example, name space name space bla

Comment: If you look a the SQL you'll see that it contains `OR`. So it will match one, or the other, or both just fine.

Comment: Ok, what about ordering the results so that if the first condition is met it shows up first? See pic added to description.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that adding something like `.order("ASC position(? in your_models.name)", term)` should do the trick.